# which layer does Netfilter and IPTables works on in the OSI model?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

`IPTables` are the basic and very commonly used firewall in Linux systems. `netfilter` provides 5 hooks that programs can register with.

which layer does Netfilter and IPTables works on?

- IP Packet level
- TCP/UDP Packet Level

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is not going to be a simple answer, as nftables/iptables acts on multiple layers of these models.

The most basic `ip[6]tables` rules (or `ip`, `ip6` and `inet` address families for nftables) mostly act on the OSI network layer (Internet layer on TCP/IP model). But `arptables` and `ebtables` (or the `arp`, `bridge` and `netdev` address families for nftables) will operate on the OSI data-link layer, and even basic `ip[6]` tables is at least aware of which datalink (physical interface, aggregation or a virtual interface) is being used.

For any rules that include a protocol specification (for `ip[6]tables`, anything including a `-p` option; for nftables, anything with the `protocol` keyword) will operate on the transport layer too.

If connection tracking is involved, that implies at least awareness of the OSI session layer; anything implementing NAT will definitely manipulate the session layer information, and if protocol-specific NAT modules (= modules like `nf_nat_ftp`) are used, they may reach as high into the OSI presentation/application layers as required for that particular protocol/application.

So you could say that nftables (or the combination of iptables + arptables + ebtables) can affect just about any OSI layer except the physical one.